# Are mutable input iterators valid according to the standard?

Tags: c++

I'm currently implementing a input iterator façade for a Java-style enumerator (see example).

```
Enumerator enum = source.enumerator();
while(enum.has_next()) {
  auto y = enum.next();
  //do something with y
}
```

The façade is modeled after `std::istream_iterator`, calling `next` when the iterator is incremented. The current value is stored in the iterator.

Due to some requirements in the object model traversed by the enumerator, I can't simply apply constness to the member typedefs of the iterator (`pointer`, `reference`) and must return a mutable reference/pointer to the extracted value in `operator*` and `operator->`.

Does such an approach model a valid input iterator according to the C++ standard?

Comment: I'm hard pressed to believe the claim that you can't add `const` to `reference`. After all, you're adding it to **your** `operator*`.

Comment: I can't as the returned type may be a wrapper to a shared component (from a different DLL/SO) and that may not be compatible with const correctness… (e.g. another enumerator to a nested collection)